# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet JAX-RS Servlet is not available

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I tried creating restful webservice using Eclipse and followed all the steps mentioned at

> http://shrikantuw.blogspot.in/2012/03/jersy-developing-restful-web-service.html

but when I try to run in tomcat and hit the

```
http://localhost:8080/RestFulWS/rest/exampleWithOutParam/getName
```

I'm getting

> HTTP Status 404 - Servlet JAX-RS Servlet is not available

My tomcat port is also 8080 only.

kindly let me what should I do.

Comment: What happens if you go to that page directly via a browser on the localhost server? Do you get the same error? My guess is that you don't have the servlet in the right location, so you're getting a 404, eg "can't find the page".

Comment: Double check your url pattern and resource paths added in code using @Path annotations. Try going to http://localhost:8080/RestFulWS/rest/application.wadl Jersey usually automatically creates a WADL file describing all your resources, chceck if they match the path you're passing.

Comment: why don't you just put actual web.xml content and web-service code here?

Answer (score 1):

If your web.xml and service class is mapped as below, it should work properly:

Your url:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestFulWS/rest/exampleWithOutParam/getName
```

web.xml:

```
<display-name>RestFulWS</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yourapp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your service:

```
package com.yourapp;
// imports here
@Path("/exampleWithOutParam")
public class YourService {
     @GET
     @Path("/getName")
     @Produces("text/plain")
     public Response getName() {
        return Response.ok("OK").build();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the jersey jars are indeed part of your web service (that is they are in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the web service bundle when deployed in tomcat).

Answer (score 1):

```
     <display-name>RestFulWS</display-name>
     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servletclass>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>com.yourapp</param-value>
     </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

your web.xml file shoud be like this . to map servlet class and you root resource class.